# write|read mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

Добрый день.
Хочу использовать мутекс в режиме write|read, когда читает любое количество потоков, а записывает только один.

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915152/c11-multiple-read-and-one-write-thread-mutex) советую shared_mutex, но он вроде как только в C++17 (как минимум в VS 2015 нету его, только shared_lock).

Как правильнее делать такой захват?

Answer (score 2):

Если boost не подходит, тогда остаётся использовать ОС-зависимые решения. Т.к. Вы используете MSVC, тогда Вам должен подойти [SRW lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx). Если же нужна кроссплатформенность, тогда можно ОС-зависимые решения обернуть в свой класс. Но, вообще говоря, в таком случае лучше использовать boost и всё.

Answer (score 1):

В новые стандарты C++ (11, 14, 17) очень многие вещи перекочевывают из [boost](http://www.boost.org)'a. Поэтому, если Вам нужна функциональность [shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), но она не поддерживается еще Вашим компилятором, попробуйте воспользоваться бустом. В последствие, когда shared_mutex появиться в стандарте, просто откажетесь от буста.

Comment: хочется шаблон сделать без сторонних либ.
Когда С++17 выйдет, я уже забью на эту програмку

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите [pthread_rwlock_rdlock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_rdlock)/[pthread_rwlock_wrlock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_wrlock) (и SEE ALSO в этих манах) из [pthreads](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads)

Comment: У него же Visual Studio, Вы что.

Comment: @ixSci, действительно, винда... Если за последние годы pthreads туда еще не перенесли, то мне его жаль. (пусть уходит на нормальную систему :-))

Comment: На винде есть свои механизмы, которые не хуже pthreads

Comment: @ixSci, я уверен, что в винде есть почти все (даже `\\` как разделитель элементов path), но я ее как площадку для программирования не воспринимаю.